# i have a do while loop in c++ but im trying to convert it to a python code

Tags: python

I'm trying to find the root so i tried converting this c++ function into python but it wont work

```
float computeRoot(float root,int index) {
    float tp,mid,low=0.0,high=root;
    do {
         mid=(low+high)/2;
         if(computePower(mid,index)>root)
            high=mid;
         else
            low=mid;
         mid=(low+high)/2;
         tp=(computePower(mid,index)-root);
         if (tp < 0) {
           //grab absolute value
           tp=-tp;
         }
     }while(tp>.000005); //accuracy of our root
    return mid;
}
```

This is the python code

```py
def computeRoot(a,b):
    tp, mid,low = 0.0
    while tp > 0.000005:

        high = a
        mid = (low +high) / 2
        if Power(mid, b)> a:
            high = mid
        else:
            low = mid
            mid = (low + high)/2
            tp = (Power(mid, b)- a)
            if tp <0:
                tp =-tp

    print(mid)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code will look like this in python:

```py
def computeRoot(root,index):
    tp = 0
    mid = 0
    low = 0
    high = root
    while tp > 0.000005:
        mid = (low + high)/2
        if computePower(mid, index) > root:
            high = mid
        else:
            low = mid
        tp = computePower(mid,index) - root
        if (tp < 0):
            tp=-tp
    return mid
```

but you want something like this (nth root of a number):

```py
def computeRoot(root,index):
    if (index == 0):
        return 1
    else:
        return pow(root,(1/index))
```

Comment: I think your indentation is off a bit

Comment: Dude, you had types in the parameters, semicolons, bad indentation... Everything is fixed now ;)

Comment: @JosepJoestar Thanks for the Edit man, agree looks much better this way :)

Comment: @Ahmed Ahmed Thanks for the comment I updated the answer

Comment: The user must specify the number and the nth-root desired.

Comment: what is index its not defined plus the way you put float and int is wrong in python

Answer (score 0):

A `do-while` loop is guaranteed to once before the condition is checked. The corresponding idiom in Python is to use an infinite loop with an explicit condition check at the *end* of the body. If the condition is true, then break. (Note the condition is negated compared to the condition in the original C.)

```
def computeRoot(root, index):
    low = 0.0
    high = root
    while True:
        mid = (low + high) / 2
        if computePower(mid, index) > root:
            high = mid
        else:
            low = mid
        mid = (low + high) / 2
        tp = computePower(mid, index) - root
        if tp < 0:
            tp = -tp
        if tp <= 0.000005:
            break
    return mid
```

In short,

```
do {
    ...
} while (<condition>)
```

becomes

```
while True:
    ...
    if not <condition>:
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

the initial value of tp is zero so your function will never get into the while loop and always return 0

If you're loocking to add a while loop on your Python code following the c++ answer you can do :

```
def computeRoot(root,b):
    tp , mid , low = 0 , 0 , 0
    while(tp>0.000005):
        high = root
        mid = (low+high) / 2
        if mid**b> root:
            high = mid
        else:
            low = mid
        mid = (low + high)/2
        tp = (mid**b)- root
        if tp <0:
            tp =-tp
    return mid
```

Note that power(a,b) function in Python can be translated by a**b

Comment: if mid**b> a:   what is a its not defined